# Android RelativeLayout programmatically Set "centerInParent"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a *RelativeLayout* like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negativeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/black_menu_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/positiveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_menu_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to be able to programatically set for `positiveButton` the same effect as:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

How can I make this programatically ?

Answer (score 426, accepted):

Completely untested, but this *should* work:

```
View positiveButton = findViewById(R.id.positiveButton);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
positiveButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` inside your activity in your manifest

Comment: That worked, but only after I indertet layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);  before center in parent rule. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to add that this worked for me as well, but I had to change layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0); to layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, -1); in my situation. Your app may require a different value in the "anchor" field.

Comment: the anchor field value can be **anything but 0** to signify true at present. Source has the comparisons like `if (rules[CENTER_IN_PARENT] != 0 || rules[CENTER_HORIZONTAL] != 0) {` where `0` effectively evaluates to `false`

Comment: As a follow-up question does anyone know if the code in this answer can be used in animations? Like for instance animate an image from a relative left offset to a centered position etc.

Comment: you can simply use layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT), there is no need for the second parameter, as you can check in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int))

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is only working in `RelativeLayout` and not with `LinearLayout`!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that what was added should be removed before adding it again. So in order to not have many rules for one layout, you should remove the old one (layoutParams.removeRule(...)) before adding the new one. Otherwise, you may expect some weird behaviors.

Comment: thanks for this answer. but note that if you had set a Rule for your view in your XML you should first remove it. like     layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);

Answer (score 14):

Just to add another flavor from the Reuben response, I use it like this to add or remove this rule according to a condition:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtGuestName.getLayoutParams();

    if (SOMETHING_THAT_WOULD_LIKE_YOU_TO_CHECK) {
        // if true center text:
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        holder.txtGuestName.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    } else {
        // if false remove center:
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0);
        holder.txtGuestName.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

Comment: The best way to remove a rule would be:  layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout. CENTER_IN_PARENT);

Answer (score 9):

I have done for

#### 1. centerInParent

#### 2. centerHorizontal

#### 3. centerVertical

with **true** and **false**.

```
private void addOrRemoveProperty(View view, int property, boolean flag){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    if(flag){
        layoutParams.addRule(property);
    }else {
        layoutParams.removeRule(property);
    }
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

How to call method:

**centerInParent - true**

```
addOrRemoveProperty(mView, RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, true);
```

**centerInParent - false**

```
addOrRemoveProperty(mView, RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, false);
```

**centerHorizontal - true**

```
addOrRemoveProperty(mView, RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, true);
```

**centerHorizontal - false**

```
addOrRemoveProperty(mView, RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, false);
```

**centerVertical - true**

```
addOrRemoveProperty(mView, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, true);
```

**centerVertical - false**

```
addOrRemoveProperty(mView, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, false);
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin , this way :

```
private val progressBar = ProgressBar(context)
progressBar.layoutParams =
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
        val layoutParams : RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  =
            progressBar.layoutParams as  (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)

        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT)
        parentView.addView(progressBar)
```

Where parentView can be mainlayout from tour activity.