# trying to set TextView object in the center of RelativeLayout Programmatically

Tags: android

i am trying to set TextView object in the center of RelativeLayout Programmatically.
and always the TextView setting nearby center.

```
params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) N2.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(px(widthDP/2)-(px(35)),(height/2), 0, 0);
N2.setLayoutParams(params)

private int px(float dips) // return converting DP to PX
{
  float DP = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
  return Math.round(dips * DP);
}
```

thanks,
igal assis

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android RelativeLayout programatically set centerInParent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985787/android-relativelayout-programatically-set-centerinparent)

Comment: If you don't want to use `Rule` so add more information. Just my wonder what is the problem with using `Rule`?

Answer (score 1):

This will set the align_centerInParent attribute to true:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
```

Comment: hi Cruceo and thanks, i need do to this without Ruls just located with DP or PX.