# How to set ImageView in the center of layout from code?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-gravity

I try next

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams b = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                b.gravity =Gravity.CENTER;

                ivOne.setLayoutParams(b);
```

But this does no work, image view in the left side of layout

Comment: Try to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` has `centerInParent` property.

Comment: what method i must use? There are no "gravity"

Comment: LayoutParams b = new LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT | RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    b.gravity =Gravity.CENTER;
   
    ivOne.setLayoutParams(b); this does not work

Comment: @KostyaKhuta : the parent layout should be a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 3):

try to change the parent layout to `RelativeLayout` , and use the attribute `centerInParent` :

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
rootLayout.setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
ImageView ivOne = new ImageView(this);
ivOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ivOne.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
ivOne.setLayoutParams(params);
//TODO : add other views 
rootLayout.addView(ivOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly set params to your `ImageView` you should use `ImageIcons` instead

Try this:

```
ImageIcons[i] = new ImageView(this);
ImageIcons[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layoutParams.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
ImageIcons[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Hope it works.. works fine for me.!

Answer (score -1):

You could use a RelativeLayout and its centerInParent property like zozelfelfo said or you could stick with LinearLayout and try this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams b = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                ivOne.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);

                ivOne.setLayoutParams(b);
```

But in this method, your ImageView will take up the entire layout so be careful if you have other views in it too. If you do, then you're best bet is to [use RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985787/android-relativelayout-programatically-set-centerinparent)

Comment: 06-27 12:35:17.076: E/AndroidRuntime(3357): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams