# Android programmatically CENTER_IN_PARENT ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, imageview, spinner, android-relativelayout, center

OK, many apologies, I've read several posts on how to do this but I'm still unable to get exactly what I want. I have a Spinner to select what appears onscreen and I want a different layout for when the Spinner is its default position from when anything else has been selected. 
It's almost working but I'd like to get Globe CENTER_IN_PARENT when the Spinner is in it's default position. I've tried programmatically setting margins to test whether there's something fundamentally wrong andthis has worked (but not shown in the code).

My thanks in advance.

Take a look at these 2 views, the first is when the Spinner is its default, the second when it is not:-

[image: Spinner in Default]

[image: Spinner not in default]

My code

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // The variable index identifies the position the spinner is in.
            // TextView name, country and description... locks to the
            // TextViews defined in the activity_main.xml layout files.
            int index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
            TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView country = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
            TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
            TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);

            // Used to set up Layout Params for the ImageView, Name and
            // Country TextViews
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) image
                    .getLayoutParams();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) name
                    .getLayoutParams();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) country
                    .getLayoutParams();

            // Now we'll check to see if we're in the None Selected spinner
            // position. If true we'll dump the name, country and
            // description TextViews otherwise these will be shown.

            if (index == 0) {

                // Get rid of unwanted views when Spinner is at default
                // position
                name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                country.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                link.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Try and centre the image when Spinner in default position
                // The first line acquires the image, the other lines try
                // and centre the image by 1st clearing ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT
                // and then setting CENTER_IN_PARENT

                image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(
                        spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), -1));
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT,
                        RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                image.setLayoutParams(lp);

            } else {
                // Spinner is not in its default position so lay the view
                // out different by ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT
                image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(
                        spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), -1));
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,
                        RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                image.setLayoutParams(lp);

                // Now set up rules for other TextViews and make them VISIBLE
                lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                lp3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                country.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                link.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                name.setText(leaders[index]);
                country.setText(states[index]);

                description.setText(descrip[index]);
                // Do some formatting for the hyperlinks
                link.setText(links[index]);
                link.setText(Html.fromHtml(links[index]));
                link.setLinksClickable(false);
                link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

            }

        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985787/android-relativelayout-programatically-set-centerinparent

Comment: Yep, thanks Keshav, that's one of the posts I'd already looked at and checked that mine conforms to the answer posted!

Answer (score 2):

This works me:

```
val params: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = imageView.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT)
imageView.layoutParams = params

imageView.requestLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, couldn't post it in comments.

Your layout seems to be shrinking to the size of the white box in the following image [image]

To solve this problem you should change the `height` and `width` of the parent layout from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`

Do the following in the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: he need to set `ImageView` into parent center programmatically not using `XML`

Comment: @ahmedhamdy: I have not done anything to set the ImageView, I have identified the problem that the container of ImageView is shrinking to size of content and is not equal to size of screen and then put the dimensions to match screen size so that OP can center the ImageView as needed.