# How to add an ImageView to the center of the screen, by ratio

Tags: android

My code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
final int width = display.getWidth();
final int height = display.getHeight();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
relativeLayout.addView(img1,params);
params.leftMargin = width/2;
params.topMargin = height/2;
setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

Could somebody help me to fit my img1 to the center of the screen, at every resolution?
I think that the display.getwidth value is not associated with params.leftmargin.
Please instruct me to get the margin value to any use by dividing it.

Comment: Here's your answer (the REAL [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3985891/2649012))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
img1.setLayoutParams(params);
relativeLayout.addView(img1);
```

**EDIT :** if u want to add more views then u should create `layoutparams` for every view and `use addRule` method I m just giving u an example how to place a view under a view u can place that view `right , left or above` accoridngly change this `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM` and u can use `RelativeLayout.LAYOUT_BELOW` instead of `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM`

```
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, ur_view.getId());
```

> if u create it in xml it will be much more easier

if u want to set margin for any view do something like this

```
p.setMargins(left margin, top margin, right margin, bottom margin);
```

> left margin, top margin, right margin, bottom margin are Integer
>   value, which value u want to set for ur view

Comment: Yessss , Definitely the answer I want.. HThank you so much ... :)

Comment: But, don't annoy me sir. I still want to locate other pics on the relativelayout with different positions. How can i ?

Comment: can u post a screen shot of and whole scenario what u want and sorry for late reply

Comment: My scenario is to create a game about finding items. 
I set main images of puzzle at background image alternatively.
And locate items (to find) will be on the background image so to click and find it(to create Onclick)...
So, I need to locate these items on the background with the different locations. (Fixed location can cause my item to be uncovered) . So I need to know how to set the margin value with resolution proportionally ... 
Thank You so much !!:)